# What is the algebraic expression for PyTorch's ConvTranspose2d's output shape?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

When using PyTorch's ConvTranspose2d as such:

```
w = 5 # input width
h = 5 # output height
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=k, stride=s, padding=p)
```

What is the formula for the dimensions of the output in each channel? I tried a few examples and cannot derive the pattern. For some reason adding padding seems to shrink the output size (example starts with 5 x 5 as above):

```
# yields an 11 x 11 image
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0) 

# yields a 7 x 7 image
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=2)
```

Using a larger kernel or stride both increase (expected) but not at the rate that I expected:

```
# yields an 11 x 11 image
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0) 

# yields a 13 x 13 image
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=0)

# yields a 15 x 15 image
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=3, padding=0)
```

I'm sure there's a pretty simple math equation involving `w, h, k, s, p` but I can't find it in the documentation and I haven't been able to derive it myself. Normally I wouldn't ask for a math equation, but it completely affects the ability of a CNN to compile and generate the correct size. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expression for output shape (Hout) is in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula to calculate `ConvTranspose2d` output sizes is mentioned on the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#convtranspose2d) page:

> H_out ​= (H_in​−1)*stride[0] − 2×padding[0] + dilation[0]×(kernel_size[0]−1) + output_padding[0] + 1
>
> W_out​ = (Win​−1)×stride[1] − 2×padding[1] + dilation[1]×(kernel_size[1]−1)  + output_padding[1] + 1

By default, stride=1, padding=0, and output_padding=0.

For example, for

```
nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)
```

the `H_out` will be

```
H_out = (5-1)*2 - 2*0 + 1*(3-1) + 0 + 1 = 11
```